# find host ip address when guest machine is connected to host

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have an XP virtual machine on an Ubuntu installation. I can connect to the internet in the guest OS(XP). Now I want to find the ip address of the host OS(Ubuntu). I can find the guest IP address in the Connection Properties in XP, but how do I find the IP of the ubuntu machine?

You should know, I want to add a DNS record in my \system32\drivers\hosts so that I can access a virtual host in my Ubuntu (apache). Using `ifconfig`, I can see that I have only three adapter. One is my LAN adapter(ethernet), the loopback and a wireless adapters. I have even tried the Gateway address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply open xterm or press CTRL+ALT+F1 and write:

```
ifconfig
```

The "inet" string is the ip.
Of course this is the **local** IP and **not the public one**.
To obtain your **public IP** (reachable from the outside) visit [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) (or an equivalent web site) or enter in your router interface (it will tell you the public ip).
For the hosts file there is a specific guide[at www.rackspace.com](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file).

Bye, hope you will solve.

Comment: That definitely was it, Thanks a lot. I though that it was the gateway of my DSL router

Comment: Using the public IP to reach the host from the guest is like flying from Europe to Africa via the US.

Comment: So what would be the direct route???? Your answer?

Answer (score 7):

#### Using NAT

In VirtualBox using regular NAT networking you can reach the host itself by using the gateway IP address. In Windows guest OS you can see this using the network adapter properties as shown below:

[image]

#### Host-only networking

The alternative is to connect another network adapter using "Host-only" networking as shown below.

First add a Host-only network entry in the global Virtualbox network settings:

[image]

Then add it to the networking settings of the guest:

[image]

You will then be able to reach the host at `192.168.56.1` (magic numbers here, I know!).

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude. But I don't have any options in the Name field. What should I do???

Answer (score 3):

you can use `nmap` tool. By using it you can find the Host IP too.

assume that your IP addresses wills start from 192.168.1.1 then If you would like to see all the systems which are in the given range

```
nmap 192.168.1.1-255
```

thats for scanning all from 1-255 range.

if you have a firewall protected host then you can use

```
nmap -PN 192.168.1.1-255
```

hope that helps.